# Global architecture presence user connected

Tags: java, javascript, spring, node.js, sockets

I had before a project where i need to push data(websocket) to the client i used spring and atmosphere framework(an abstract of websocket in java). But finally i think actually websocket app in java are not enough good since i used nodejs&socket.io for an another project. It was so easy and a great experience to code an push data api.

So now i am thinking about an architecture and i want to share with you to know if its a good practices.

I have my server spring, client and nodejs/socket.io. I want to use nodejs just to store de socket and push event.
So imagine the server has to push data to specific users i will call a service in nodejs and he will push it.

So the nodejs API will just redirect requests to a user, nothing more.

Is that a good practice ?

Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you decouple java application server and nodejs (socket server) and communicate using a middleware (messaging system..)

[image: Exmaple architecture]

Let's say your java application is running on http://abc.com:1234 and socket.io on http://abc.com:5678. Then when the page is opened you can subscribe of the socket server.

Once you have some data to push, put it on middleware. SocketIO server will pick it up from there and pushes to all the browser client subscribed.

Comment: Great answer i am going to check how to handle all this things